# Unordered list navbar elements have strange gaps

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to write a navigation bar using an `<ul>` with `inline` elements, but the elements all have a gap between them that seem to come from nowhere. That is when hovering a link, the shaded box should snap to the surrounding boxes. The page currently looks like this: http://wictorht.at.ifi.uio.no/. What is causing these gaps?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul class="header">
            <li class="title">wictorht</li>
            <li class="header">
            <a class="header" href="https://bitbucket.org/htor/dwmst/src">dwms</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header">
            <a class="header" href="https://bitbucket.org/htor/linux/src">linux</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header">
            <a class="header" href="http://www.fsf.org/register_form?referrer=10397">fsf</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header">
            <a class="header" href="http://stackexchange.com/users/1006063">stackexhange</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #666666;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0;
}

a.header {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

a.header:hover, a.header:active {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

ul.header {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: #666666;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

li.header {
    display: inline;
}

li.title {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #bada55;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because all white-space, including new-lines, between elements is collapsed down to a single space when rendered by the client's browser. To hide the spaces you can either:

1. Remove the spaces between `li` elements:

   ```
   <li><!-- content --></li><li><!-- more content --></li>
   ```
2. Set the `font-size` of the parent `ul` to `0`, and redefine the `font-size` of the `li` element:

   ```
   ul {
       font-size: 0;
   }

   ul li {
       font-size: 14px;
   }
   ```
3. Comment out the gaps between the `li` elements:

   ```
   <li>Content</li><!--
   --><li>Next li</li>
   ```
4. Float the `li` elements instead of using `display: inline`, which removes the spaces by taking the elements out of the normal flow:

   ```
   ul {
       overflow: hidden; /* to keep the li 'visibily' within the bounds of the ul */
   }

   ul li {
       float: left;
   }
   ```
5. Close the `li` tag on the next line, before the next `li` opening tag this feels slightly wrong to me, but it *is* valid:

   ```
   <li>First li</li
   ><li>Second li</li>
   ```

(Or, obviously, place the *next* `li` opening-tag on the previous line, immediately after the previous element's closing tag:

```
    <li>First li</li><
    li>Second li</li>
```

)

Answer (score 2):

The gaps are caused by the whitespace between the `<li></li>` tags.
Try `<li>...</li><li>...</li>` as a comparison.

Anyways, avoid this with `display:block` and using `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great post explaining what is happening and the work arounds that have already been mentioned by the previous answers.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

You also have a little trouble with your css selector names, you actually only need one class and you can take advantage of the nature of CSS to do the rest.

```
.header {
   background-color: #c1c1c1;
   color: #666666;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Now target all the 'li' tags that are children of the .header class

```
.header li {
   display: inline;
 }
```

Now target all the 'a' tags that are children of the .header class (these happen to be inside your 'li' tags)

```
 .header a {
   /* etc */
 }
```